# Como mostrar una foto en ASP.NET MVC Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

tengo un formulario de registro personalizado en el que guardo una foto de quién se registra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen se guarda como un **array de bytes** en la base de datos sql. 
En el controlador Home he creado el siguiente método:

```
 public FileContentResult getImage()
        {
            var owin = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            var result = owin.FindByEmail<ApplicationUser, string>(User.Identity.Name);

            byte[] biteIMG = result.Logo;

            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(biteIMG);


            Image image = Image.FromStream(m);

            m = new MemoryStream();

            image.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png);

            m.Position = 0;


            return new FileContentResult(biteIMG, "image/png");
        }
```

Y cuando ingreso a la ruta siguiente https://localhost:44397/Home/getImage,  la imagen se ve perfectamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo lo que quiero es que aparezca la imagen en un div o en un image de html pero en el html del Home  o simplemente mostrarla en cualquier parte o en cualquier otro controlador . He intentado lo siguiente pero no funciona:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También intenté lo siguiente y no funciona:

```
 <img src="https://localhost:44397/Home/getImage" alt="avatar" />
```

Alguien sabe como hacer esto de poder ponerla en un `div` o `image` en html5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder visualizar tu imagen en un control del tipo `<img />`, debes utilizar el *HtlmHelper* **`@Url.Action()`**.

Desde la Vista en la que quieres mostrar la imagen, debes llamar a la Acción `getImage` del Controlador `Home` en el atributo **`src=`** de tu `<img />`.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="container">        
       <img src="@Url.Action("getImage","Home")" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hombre gracias. Eso si sirvió